# Toggling event listeners on html element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a basic scroll forever feature. I want to be able to load remote content via ajax when a particular div receives focus or is within a certain offset. This part of my code works alright, but the problem is that the function I have attached to my event listener fires multiple times. I have tried detaching the listeners via jquery `.off()` within the function itself. but this will mean my function will only work ones after page load. but I want to be able to reattach the listener back to the div, when user scrolls to the div subsequent times, the function is once again executed.

this is what I have been doing so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on('scroll',scrollLoader);
     //attaches eventlistener
});

 var page = 10; 
function scrollLoader(){


        var hT = $('#load-more').offset().top,
            hH = $('#load-more').outerHeight(),
            wH = $(window).height(),
            wS = $(this).scrollTop();
            var jsArray, reason, items = "";

        if (wS > ((hT+hH-wH)-50)){ //500


            $(window).off('scroll');
            //detaches event listener

             page =  page + 1;
            console.log("page: " +page);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'class.index.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: "origin=index",
                success: function (data) {
                     jsArray = data;
                const arrayData = data;
                console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(arrayData)));

                Array.prototype.forEach.call(JSON.parse(arrayData), function(item, index){

                    //stuff gets done here

                });

                    $("#ajax-post").append(items);

                    //console.log(items);
                },
                cache: false
            });






        }
        //$(window).on('scroll',scrollLoader);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Maxwell  You can try debouncing your listener.
Or better even use  intersection observer for it.It will make your life much simpler.

Let me know if you need more help with this.

This  is how you debounce a function. It makes sure function is invoked after a certain time after it's previous invocation.

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => { 
    let debounceTimer 
    return function() { 
        const context = this
        const args = arguments 
            clearTimeout(debounceTimer) 
                debounceTimer 
            = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay) 
    } 
}
```

[Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, thanks to pointers provided by @pradhyumn, I have been able to put together something that works. using Debounce was not just the solution, but it also made my code more efficient considering how many times the function could potentially be executed.

```
var page = 10;
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
};
};

var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
// All the taxing stuff you do
            var hT = $('#load-more').offset().top,
            hH = $('#load-more').outerHeight(),
            wH = $(window).height(),
            wS = $(this).scrollTop();
            var jsArray, reason, items = "";

        if (wS > ((hT+hH-wH)-50)){ //500
            console.log('comment box section arrived! eh');
            //alert("egegegeeee");
            // After Stuff
            $(window).off('scroll');
             page =  page + 1;
            console.log("page: " +page);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'class.index.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: "origin=index",
                success: function (data) {
                     jsArray = data;
                const arrayData = data;
                console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(arrayData)));

                Array.prototype.forEach.call(JSON.parse(arrayData), function(item, index){

                    //console.log(item,index);

                    items += '<div class="box-typical box-typical-padding documentation no-border">' +
                        '<div class="flex-container">' +
                            '<div class="main-showcase">'+
                            '<span class="text-uppercase"> + reason + <br></span>'  +
                                '<span class="story-title-a scale-topic">' + item[1] +'</span>' +
                                '<p class="card-text story-intro">' +
                                    item[5] +
                                '</p>' +

                                '<span class="card-text story-intro"> '+item[8]+' * '+item[6]+' read  </span>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="second-showcase" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 112px; background-image: url(\''+ item[7] +'\'); background-size:cover;">' +

                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';   

                });

                    $("#ajax-post").append(items);

                    //console.log(items);
                },
                cache: false
            });






        }
        //$(window).on('scroll',scrollLoader);
    }, 350);

 window.addEventListener('scroll', myEfficientFn);
```